# Merkle Hash forest and MErkle DAG is it the same?

Tags: sparse-markle-trees

I'm wondering if a merkle hash forest is the same as a merkle dag? I need a reliable paper as reference I could cite in my paper.
Thx for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. Although the spec is outdated, you can find the reference in the old IPFD fit page : https://github.com/ipfs/specs/blob/master/merkledag/README.md